# dimens.xml for different layouts don't work in my favor

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm encountering a problem with creating `dimens.xml` for different layout:
[image: My dimens.xml files]

If I use these files, the layout won't work properly. I have tried this method with my Redmi 5 Plus phone and my layout was just broken.
But if I delete all of these folders and leave the original `dimens.xml` file out, the layout will work properly like before. What have I done wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Hello henry there is no need to add values folder each time you add dimens for a 
different version just create one value folder and add all the dimens in that.
You have to create different versions of dimens not the values.
Still if you face the error then show me the .xml code